# windows 10 on virtualbox linux webcam not working

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux, webcam

i  am using arch Linux .

i have installed **virtual box** and i ran windows on it but it seems i have a problem with my **camera driver**. i have installed the CD guest addition to enable the webcam.

in my device manager the camera has like a yellow triangle warning.

i have tried reinstalling the **CD guest addition**( from the official virtual box website) can someone help?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you’re not using USB passthrough? I think it could work better (or at all, in your case).

Comment: you mean booting live using a usb? @DanielB

Comment: No. VirtualBox does not only have a dedicated webcam feature, it also has a general USB device passthrough feature where you can attach (almost) any USB device to the VM, as if it were connected directly.

Comment: oh yes but i mean  my main  camera driver isn't working it has a yellow warning triangle on the camera driver in device manager. i am not using an external camera @DanielB

Comment: When using USB passthrough, the real device will be visible to your Windows guest and the real driver (totally unrelated to VirtualBox) will be used. When using the VirtualBox-specific webcam feature, an emulated device (_not_ the real device) will be visible to your guest and a VirtualBox-specific driver will be used. These two methods are _very_ different. Make sure you try both. Perhaps also clarify in your question which methods you have problems with. My impression is that you were trying to use the VirtualBox-specific webcam feature.